# kenken solver, python

Tags: python, beginner

I have written a series of functions to solve [kenkens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KenKen). The general strategy is to eliminate possibilities until only one remains for each cell. This first function eliminates all possibilities that can't be used to satisfy the operation and target constraints.

I'm interested in any feedback concerning style and efficiency.

```py
from itertools import product
from itertools import combinations

#set size of square board
side = 9

#each cell of the grid is identified by an index        
indices = [i for i in range(side*side)]

#each cell is located in a row and in a column
addresses = []
index2row = []
index2column = []
for x in range(side):
    for y in range(side):
        addresses.append([x,y])
        index2row.append(x)
        index2column.append(y)

#each row and column is a list of indices
rows = []
a = 0
b = side
for r in range(side):
    row = []
    for i in indices[a:b]:
        row.append(i)
    rows.append(row)
    a = b
    b = b+side

columns = []
for c in range(side):
    column = []
    a = c
    for i in range(side):
        column.append(a)
        a = a + side
    columns.append(column)

#initially each cell can be any number from 1 to the number side
possibilities = []
for i in range(side*side):
    lp = []
    for n in range(1, side+1):
        lp.append(n)
    possibilities.append(lp)

#initially the solution for each cell is set at 0
values = [0 for i in range(side * side)]



##define Cage class
class Cage:
    def __init__(self, indexes, operation, target):

        self.indexes = indexes #cells in cage
        self.operation = operation #arithmetic operation
        self.target = target #result of operation e.g. 2 by division


##operation functions       
def multiplication(combination):
    result = 1
    for n in combination:
        result = result*n
    return(result)

def subtraction(pair):
    return(abs(pair[0] - pair[1]))

def division(pair):
    return(max([pair[0]/pair[1], pair[1]/pair[0]]))

def addition(combination):
    return(sum(combination))

def equals(combination):
    return(combination[0])

#sample puzzle, indices, operations and targets for each cage
indexes = [[0,1,9,10],[2,3],[4,12,13],[5,14],[6,7],[8,17,26],[11,20],[15,24],[16,25],[18,27,36,45],
           [19,28,37],[21,22,31],[23,32,41,50,59],[29,38],[30,39],[33,42],[34,43,52],[35,44],[40,49],
           [46,54,55],[47,48],[51,60],[53,62],[56,57],[58,67,68,77],[61],[63,72],[64,73,74],[65],
           [66,75,76],[69,70,71],[78,79,80]]



operations = [multiplication,subtraction,addition,division,addition,multiplication,
              multiplication,division,subtraction,
              multiplication,addition,multiplication,addition,
              multiplication,division,subtraction,multiplication,subtraction,
              addition,addition,division,addition,addition,
              subtraction,addition,equals,
              subtraction,addition,equals,multiplication,addition,multiplication]

targets = [1344,5,20,2,15,15,24,2,2,648,14,120,35,56,4,5,18,5,6,12,3,11,13,1,16,8,3,19,1,48,18,210]                            
#assemble indexes, operations and targets for all cages into list 'cages'
cages = []
for i in range(len(targets)):
    cage = Cage(indexes[i], operations[i], targets[i])
    cages.append(cage)


##1 remove numbers that can't be used to produce target
##e.g. 2 by division eliminates 5,7,9 
## 8 by subtraction leaves only 1 and 9, 2-8 are eliminated
def cullPossibilities(possibilities):
    for cage in cages:
        if all([possibilities[i] == [] for i in cage.indexes]):
            continue #test if all cells in cage have been solved, if so move to 
                     #next cage
        listsPossibilities = [] #assemble list of possibilities from cage cells
        for index in cage.indexes:
            if possibilities[index] != []:
                listsPossibilities.append(possibilities[index])
            else:
                listsPossibilities.append([values[index]])
        combinations = list(product(*listsPossibilities)) 
        #generate combinations of possibilities from cells in cage
        combinations = [list(combination) for combination in combinations] 
        #test which satisfy target
        targetCombinations = []
        for combination in combinations:
            if cage.operation(combination) == cage.target:
             #check for duplicates using set and length of list
                if len(combination) == len(set(combination)):
                    targetCombinations.append(combination)
                else:
                    rowAddresses = [index2row[index] for index in cage.indexes]
                    testRow = list(zip(combination, rowAddresses))
                    columnAddresses = [index2column[index] for index in 
                         cage.indexes]
                    testColumn = list(zip(combination, columnAddresses))
                    if len(testColumn) == len(set(testColumn)) and len(testRow) 
                                                  == len(set(testRow)):
                        targetCombinations.append(combination)
        # if target is satisfied and there are no duplicates add to new list of
         #possibilities which replaces original list of possibilities           
        i = 0
        for index in cage.indexes:
            newPossibilities = [targetCombination[i] for targetCombination in targetCombinations]
            if possibilities[index] != []:
                possibilities[index] = list(set(newPossibilities))
            i = i + 1

    return(possibilities)
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! Could you post how this function is to be called and show a sample input/output? I'm not sure what `possibilities` is supposed to look like. Thanks.

Comment: possibilities is a list of the numbers being considered as a solution for a given cell.

Comment: where do I post the additional code to demonstrate how the function is called?

Comment: OK. What might that look like? Just random numbers from -infinity..infinity and the list can be any length? You can edit the post to show what a KenKen board looks like being solved by your algorithm. See the [edit link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/242079/edit) above this comment section and slightly to the left.

Comment: Thanks for the additional code, however, I still feel very in the dark about how the code works--it feels a bit like a wall of text. I recommend looking at [this upvoted KenKen post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162933/a-kenken-puzzle-solver-in-python) which guides readers through the code.

Comment: kenken is a number puzzle played on a square grid. I've added the setup for a 9x9 puzzle. The cells must be filled with the numbers 1-9 such that there are no duplicates in any row or column. An additional set of constraints involves a set of cages: groups of cells that must satisfy some arithmetical rule. For example: the values of the cells must equal 2 by division.

Comment: Please make this part of your question, comments are just for discussion. See the above link to get a sense of what a solid, answerable post looks like. Without a bit more context, the post might remain unanswered, or answers that do arrive will be cursory and unsatisfying for you.

Comment: I've added annotation to try to convey my thought process.

Comment: the referenced KenKen post was very helpful. Thank you.